# what does this construct do in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i really tried to understand, what meaning the the following contruct has in JS, but i could not figure out:

- how it works
- why & in which situation this construct should be used?

Pls could someone can tell me? Thank you!

```
(function () {
    ...
}());


// Or in jQuery plugins i saw it very often

(function( $ ){
    ...
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: possible duplicate of a bunch of questions I wish I could search for.

Comment: Maybe it is a duplicate in a way but have you tried to find answers to it? I bet it's not that easy to do without knowing the name of it.

Comment: @mkilmanas hence he says he wishes he could search for it. We need a code search engine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(function () {
    ...
}());
```

Defines a function. Calls it immediately. Doesn't store it anywhere.

Usually used to limit the scope of variables inside it.

```
(function( $ ){
    ...
})( jQuery );
```

Exactly the same, except it has an argument. Used so the unhelpfully non-descriptive variable `$` can be used without having namespace conflicts with all the other libraries that thought `$` was a good name for a variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is called Closure and it's main point is to encapsulate your inner code in order not to mix it with a global scope.

[Read this](http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/) for more details

Comment: It's not a closure >_<. It's not closing over anything (useful)

Answer (score 0):

The second part

```
(function( $ ){
    ...
})( jQuery );
```

Is used to enable your code to use $ as a reference to the jQuery object, without it conflicting with other javascript libraries (like Prototype).

See the jQuery documentation:
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries#Referencing_Magic_-_Shortcuts_for_jQuery

Answer (score 0):

These are closures.  There is tons of information on this style of JavaScript programming but the gist of it is that its an immediately executing function.  If you look closely at the syntax this makes perfect sense -

`( )` causes an execution to take place.

```
//Function immediately executes.
(function() {

});

//Wait we can do better, let's pass in an argument
(function($) {
    //$ is now a local variable inside this tightly scoped function
    //So that I can describe this as a closure I've added members to this function

    var foo = 0,
        bar = function() {
           return foo;
        };

    return {
       foo: bar
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: My pedantry says your use of "closure" and "immediately executing function" are incorrect.

Comment: @Raynos oops let me return something.

Comment: that does not solve the problem. The pedantry is that a function is not a closure unless it closes over free variables (it does not). There are no immediately executing functions. There are only functions that _can be_ immediately executed. "Immediately executing" is not a property of a function, it's an action you can apply to a function.

Comment: @Raynos You're right - instead of using "immediately executing" I should have said that "this function executes immediately" since "immediately executing" doesn't necessarily describe what is happening to the function but rather that people thing that it is a property of the function (which it is not, that would be silly).  I use the term closure here because it is the basis for what builds a closure.  I know it is not wrap any members... I've added a comment to avoid any confusion.